# How does mathematical software evaluate symbolic sums?

Tags: computer-algebra

Wolfram alpha [is able to compute](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BBinomial%28j,2%29,j,1,n%5D) this sum:
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n \binom{j}{2} = \frac{1}{6}(n-1)n(n+1). $$

How can Wolfram alpha do it? What kind of algorithm does it use?

Comment: You might be able to get specifics from [mathematica.SE].

Answer (score 2):

It uses algorithms discussed in the book [A=B](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) by Petkovšek, Wilf and Zeilberger. These algorithms can compute a closed-form expression for a summation of rational functions (in your case, the rational function is $j(j-1)/2$), or determine that no such closed-form expression exists.